# Using cov() function in PDL module

Tags: perl, covariance, pdl

I want to compute covariance using `PDL`, but the problem is that it always shows an error:

> Undefined subroutine &main::cov called at line 12.

Can anyone tell me where I'm making a mistake?

```
#! usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use PDL;

my $a = random(5, 3);
my $b = random(5, 3);

print "$a\n$b\n";

my $cov = cov($a, $b);     #line 12

print "$cov\n";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message tells you that a function named `cov` is not exported by default by `PDL`.  If I search the [PDL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDL) CPAN page (using the `grep` tool), I do not see a function named `cov`.

A google search yields [PDL::Stats::Basic](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?PDL%3a%3aStats%3a%3aBasic), which has a `cov` function.

Comment: Hi, that worked. I thought that using PDL would import all the modules under it. I had to install this PDL::Stats::Basic module separately. And now it works!!

Thanks!!

Comment: It looks like `PDL::Stats` is a completely separate distribution from `PDL`.